# Can't update the version code in a PhoneGap Android application

Tags: java, android, xml, cordova

I have tried to upload a new APK for my application to Google Play but it keeps telling me the version code is still "1" when I have specifically stated in both the config.xml and the AndroidManifest.xml (main) that the version code should be "9".

This is a new android project since I lost the source for the old one in a hard drive crash.

config.xml:

```
<widget 
    xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    id = "com.phonegap.helloworld"
    version = "1.3.0"
    android-versionCode = "9"
>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:versionCode="9"
    android:versionName="1.3.0"
>
```

I have been on the hunt for an answer on multiple forums both over at Google, PhoneGap, Cordova and here but no solution so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not familiar with phonegap/cordova, but how do you build your apk? If it is with gradle (like I would recommend) set the `versionCode` in the corresponding `build.gradle`. It always overrides the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: added an answer for you to accept (if everything works fine now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your BuildTool. If it is android-gradle, the value from `build.gradle` will always override the corresponding value in `AndroidManifest.xml`.